# QueuUserAPC sometimes doesn't launc an apc routine in a thread waiting with GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, c++17, iocp

I'm working on a simple async socket client built on top of winsock with io completion ports
it sometimes works and sometimes blocks with strange behaviours

this is the design of the async process :

- there are global iocp threads running to receive the completion packets and notify submitters
- the submitters use QueueUserApc routine to make the io call in the context of one of the waiting thread
- the apc routine makes the async io call and the the a waiter thread should receive the result and notify the issuer

this is my simple wrapper for the io completion ports

```
template <class T, auto CloseFn>
struct HandleDeleter
{
    using pointer = T;
    void operator ()(pointer handle) { CloseFn(handle); }
};

using Handle = std::unique_ptr<void, HandleDeleter<HANDLE, CloseHandle>>;

struct IoContext : public OVERLAPPED
{
    IoContext()
    {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    }
};

struct CompletionResult
{
    CompletionResult() : BytesTransferred(0), Key(0), Ctx(nullptr) {}
    CompletionResult(unsigned long bytes, uintptr_t key, IoContext* ctx) : BytesTransferred(bytes), Key(key), Ctx(ctx) {}
    unsigned long BytesTransferred;
    uintptr_t Key;
    IoContext *Ctx;
};

class IoPort
{
    Handle port_handle;
    public:
    IoPort()
    {}
    IoPort(Handle&& port) : port_handle(std::move(port))
    {}
    IoPort(IoPort&& rhs) : port_handle(std::move(rhs.port_handle))
    {}

    IoPort& operator=(IoPort&& rhs)
    {
        port_handle = std::move(rhs.port_handle);
        return *this;
    }

    bool Create(unsigned int max_threads = 0);

    bool AddToPort(Handle& file, uintptr_t key);

    bool AddToPort(SOCKET sock, uintptr_t key);

    bool GetResultOrApc(CompletionResult& result, DWORD WaitTimeMs);

    void Close()
    {
        port_handle.reset();
    }

};

bool IoPort::Create(unsigned int max_threads)
{
    port_handle.reset(CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, max_threads));
    return bool(port_handle);
}

bool IoPort::AddToPort(Handle & file, uintptr_t key)
{
    return CreateIoCompletionPort(file.get(), port_handle.get(), key, 0) != nullptr;
}

bool IoPort::AddToPort(SOCKET sock, uintptr_t key)
{
    return CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)sock, port_handle.get(), key, 0) != nullptr;
}

bool IoPort::GetResultOrApc(CompletionResult & result, DWORD WaitTimeMs)
{
    OVERLAPPED_ENTRY entry = { 0 };
    DWORD count = 0;
    BOOL wait_result = GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx(port_handle.get(), &entry, 1, &count, WaitTimeMs, TRUE);
    if (entry.lpOverlapped)
    {
        result.Key = entry.lpCompletionKey;
        result.BytesTransferred = entry.dwNumberOfBytesTransferred;
        result.Ctx = (IoContext*)entry.lpOverlapped;
    }
    return wait_result;
}
```

then this is the global iocp threads that starts before entering main function

```
struct IOCPThreads
{
    iocp::IoPort Port;

    std::vector<std::thread> IoThreads;

    bool Exit = false;

    IOCPThreads()
    {
        if (!Port.Create())
        std::cout << "[!] failed to open the port , error : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        auto num = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        IoThreads.reserve(num);
        std::stringstream thd_ids;
        thd_ids << "threads ids : { ";
        for (auto i : range(0u, num))
        {
        IoThreads.emplace_back(std::thread(&IOCPThreads::IoThread, this));
        thd_ids << IoThreads[i].get_id() << ", ";
        }
        auto str = thd_ids.str();
        str.pop_back();
        str.pop_back();
        str += " }";
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }

    ~IOCPThreads()
    {
        Exit = true;
        for (auto& thd : IoThreads)
        if (thd.joinable())
            thd.join();
    }

    void IoThread()
    {
        while (!Exit)
        {
        iocp::CompletionResult result;
        Port.GetResultOrApc(result, 10);
        if (GetLastError() == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION)
            std::cout << "[*] received an apc" << std::endl; // sometimes print and sometimes no
        if (!result.Ctx)
            continue;

        DWORD transeferred, Flags;
        std::unique_ptr<ClientIoCtx> ctx((ClientIoCtx*)result.Ctx);
        WSAGetOverlappedResult(ctx->sock->GetHandle().get(), ctx.get(), &transeferred, FALSE, &Flags);
        int WsaError = WSAGetLastError();

        if (ctx->op == ClientIoOp::Recv)
        {
            std::unique_ptr<ClientIoRecvCtx> RecvCtx = unique_static_cast<ClientIoRecvCtx>(ctx);
            RecvCtx->OnResult(*RecvCtx->sock, WsaError, std::span{ RecvCtx->buffer, RecvCtx->buffer + RecvCtx->length }, transeferred);
        }
        }
    }

};

IOCPThreads ClientIoThreads;
```

and this is the socket implemention :

```
enum class async_status_code : unsigned int
{
    Pending,
    Finished,
    Error,
};

struct AsyncResult
{
    async_status_code code;
    unsigned int transferred;
    AsyncResult() : code(async_status_code::Error), transferred(0)
    {}
    AsyncResult(async_status_code c, unsigned int s) : code(c), transferred(s)
    {}
    bool IsPending() const
    {
        return code == async_status_code::Pending;
    }
    bool IsFinished() const
    {
        return code == async_status_code::Finished;
    }
    bool IsFailed() const
    {
        return code == async_status_code::Error;
    }
};

using AsyncSendFunc = std::function<void(Socket& sock, int ErrorCode, std::span<const char> Buffer, DWORD transeferred)>;

enum class SendRecvFlags
{
    UnSpecefied = 0,
    MsgDontRoute = 0x4,
    MsgOOB = 0x1,
    MsgPeek = 0x2,
    MsgWaitAll = 0x8,
    MsgPushImmediate = 0x20,
};

enum class ClientIoOp
{
    Send,
};

struct ApcResult
{
    async_status_code code;
    DWORD transeferred;
    int error;
};

struct ClientIoCtx : public IoContext
{
    Socket *sock;
    ClientIoOp op;
    promise<ApcResult> notifier;
};

struct ClientIoSendCtx : public ClientIoCtx
{
    ClientIoSendCtx() { op = ClientIoOp::Send; }
    const char *buffer;
    int length;
    SendRecvFlags flags;
    AsyncSendFunc OnResult;
};

AsyncResult LIB_NAMESPACE::net::Socket::AsyncSend(const char * buffer, int length, io::IoContext & IoCtx, SendRecvFlags flags)
{
    WSABUF buff_vec{ length, (char*)buffer };
    DWORD sent = 0;
    if (WSASend(sock.get(), &buff_vec, 1, &sent, (DWORD)flags, &IoCtx, nullptr) == 0)
        return AsyncResult(async_status_code::Finished, sent);
    else if (WSAGetLastError() == WSA_IO_PENDING)
        return AsyncResult(async_status_code::Pending, sent);
    return AsyncResult();
}

AsyncResult LIB_NAMESPACE::net::Socket::AsyncSend(const char * buffer, int length, const AsyncSendFunc & OnSend, SendRecvFlags flags)
{   
    ClientIoSendCtx *ctx = new ClientIoSendCtx();
    ctx->sock = this;
    ctx->buffer = buffer;
    ctx->length = length;
    ctx->flags = flags;
    ctx->OnResult = OnSend;
    auto fut = ctx->notifier.get_future(); // notifier is a promise

    auto& thd = ClientIoThreads.IoThreads[RandomUInt(0, ClientIoThreads.IoThreads.size() - 1)];
    std::cout << "[*] launchin the apc routine in thread : " << thd.get_id() << std::endl; // it's always one of the io threads
    auto dwRes = QueueUserAPC(Socket::ApcRoutine, thd.native_handle(), (ULONG_PTR)ctx);
    if (!dwRes) // doesn't happen
    {
        delete ctx;
        std::cout << "QueueUserAPC failed with error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return AsyncResult();
    }

    auto result = fut.get(); // --> blocks here because the apc routine doesn't start

    WSASetLastError(result.error); // the wsa error is thread local so I transfer it from the apc thread to this thread

    return AsyncResult(result.code, result.transeferred);
}

void ApcRoutine(unsigned long long Param)
{
    std::cout << "[*] ApcRoutine started" << std::endl; // sometimes is printed and sometimes no

    std::unique_ptr<ClientIoCtx> ctx((ClientIoCtx*)Param);


    if (ctx->op == ClientIoOp::Send)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<ClientIoSendCtx> SendCtx = unique_static_cast<ClientIoSendCtx>(ctx);
        auto async_result = SendCtx->sock->AsyncSend(SendCtx->buffer, SendCtx->length, *SendCtx, SendCtx->flags);
        ApcResult apc_result;
        apc_result.code = async_result.code;
        apc_result.transeferred = async_result.transferred;
        apc_result.error = WSAGetLastError();
        SendCtx->notifier.set_value(apc_result);
        if (apc_result.code != async_status_code::Error)
            SendCtx.release();
    }
}
```

the problem is that the QueuUserApc sometimes doesn't fail but the apc routine doesn't start so the the issuer thread blocks waiting with future::get

I checked the GetLasError() value every time after calling QueuUserApc and it is always 0 so what is wrong here ?

Comment: for what you at all call `QueueUserAPC` ?

Comment: because the thread that started the async io request must be running until the result comes or the io request will fail with error ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED so I want to ensure that the io request will last until it is completed . I left apc routines and used a thread safe queue instead but I think I should use neither of them as you said because I think the issuer thread shouldn't exit if it wants to receive the result

Comment: *thread that started the async io request must be running until the result comes or the io request will fail with error ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED* this was before vista, because io request always as queued in thread object and canceled if thread exit. but in modern systems (if you not support xp/2003) when you use iocp on file - i/o request is queued to file object (instead thread) and thread can exit, but request will be not canceled. but even in xp - not need queue APC in such situation. because this i still can not understand for what you use apc, if you use iocp completion

Comment: @RbMm yes I think I should make the io request directly . but can you mention where to find in doc "this was before vista, because io request always as queued in thread object and canceled if thread exit. but in modern systems (if you not support xp/2003) when you use iocp on file - i/o request is queued to file object (instead thread) and thread can exit, but request will be not canceled" ? I don't remember that the documentation said anything about being this related to pre vista

Comment: what i say based not on documentation, but on my research. new(from vista) function exist in kernel `IopQueueIrpToFileObject` for this. inside `IopSynchronousServiceTail` in 2003/xp system unconditional call [`IopQueueThreadIrp`](https://github.com/udaypydi/WRK-1.2/blob/master/base/ntos/io/iomgr/internal.c#L7468) but now can call and `IopQueueIrpToFileObject` here (depend are you use apc or iocp completion)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pg2sxz

Comment: in any case you not need here use apc at all (even in xp). you bind file to iocp. and associate file handle with some c++ object. you need add reference to c++ object which encapsulated file before begin io. if io request fail synchronous (will be no packet queued to iocp) - direct call yourself completion routine on object. otherwise - when io finished - packet will be queued to iocp. you pop it with `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`and call completion. here you handle io result and dereference object